# How can I combine search fields to find answers from a specific author in my favorite questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search

I'm trying to search `user:1271826  infavorites:5175709` but the result is empty.

`5175709` is my userID
`1271826` is [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1271826/rob)'s ID

I also tried placing `&`, `&&` in between but none worked. Is there any workaround or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: answers can't be favorited, so i don't think this'll be possible using the infavorites filter